# Jenkins, how can I archive a single subdirectory (without it's whole tree structure above)?

Tags: ios, jenkins, ios-frameworks

I'm using Jenkins to do nightly build of an iOS static framework. The output that I care about is in this directory:

ios/build/Release-iphoneuniversal/MySpecialProject.framework

I'd like to use the "Archive the artifacts" action to archive "MySpecialProject.framework", but when I do this, it creates a whole archive with the entire leading directory structure. The docs say to look at how Ant does this. I'm not familiar with Ant, so I'm at a loss here.

The main point of this is to make the "MySpecialProject.framework" available as as artifact to other projects being built with Jenkins. So, thinking that I could use the "Copy Artifact" plugin to do that.  But I can't really get past this thing where it creates a full directory structure here. I just wan "MySpecialProject.framework" to be the top-level artifact.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed my own problem, by putting in an "Execute Shell" command:

```
mv ios/build/Release-iphoneuniversal/MySpecialProject.framework .
```

Then in the post-build action, "Archive the artifacts", I was able to just archive "MySpecialProject.framework/**"

This seems to work quite well. Since each time Jenkins runs the job, it creates a new workspace, I don't have to worry about issues with "mv". Works fine.

Comment: _each time Jenkins runs the job, it creates a new workspace_ – this doesn't seem to be the case for my simple job, so I use this command: `rsync -a --delete "ios/build/Release-iphoneos/Awesome.framework" .`